# How do I edit a file in ssh

Tags: editing

How do I edit a file in ssh.
I have enter the command
vi /var/www/joomla/sites/default/info.txt

The file was open,
I enter "j" to move my arrow down. But how do I add script?

Comment: Google "vi tutorial" it's not bad once you learn it, but that's exactly what you have to do is learn how to use vi which is a common editor.

Comment: I hate to say this but without the *basics* - what OS you are running, and what you're trying to do, your question is pretty hard to answer definitively. You really need to spend a little time learning the *fundamentals*, and ask better, more detailed questions, backed up by your own research. I'd strongly suggest looking through your questions and improving them, and trying to make it clearer what your end goal is, rather than the current intermediate step

Answer (score 1):

If you have [nano,](http://www.nano-editor.org/download.php) you can use it to edit files by typing this into the terminal:

```
sudo nano (insert file-path here)
```

If you don't need root permissions to acsess the file, or you are logged in as root, take off the sudo part.

if you don't have nano, you can download it [here](http://www.nano-editor.org/download.php), or with apt-get. using apt-get is easier if your device supports it. To download & install with apt-get,

```
sudo apt-get install nano
```

Comment: nano is the better option here. While its a reasonable assumption that the OP's using ubuntu, he might have a different distro, and may or may not be able to install software.

Comment: nano works with most distros. http://www.nano-editor.org/download.php

Comment: Oh certainly. It might be a RH based distro (in which case he needs to use yum), and he might be on a limited account. I've no issue with your answer. The question on the other hand, needs a bit of love from the OP